# Constructions of the form “zum + Infinitival noun + bringen / kommen”

Tags: verb-usage, infinitive

Under the topic of infinitives, my grammar book<sup>[1]</sup> notes the construction “*zum + infinitival noun + bringen / kommen*” is used as a phrasal verb to express the completion of an action.  Two examples are offered:

> *zum Halten bringen / kommen* – bring / come to a stop
>
> *zum Kochen bringen / kommen* – bring/come to the boil

I then tried to find examples of these constructions in full sentences and after checking Duden, canoonet.eu, I found the following examples on linguee.com:

> (a)   Wie aber können wir unser Raumschiff am Ziel **zum Halten
>   bringen**, ohne Treibstoff zum Abbremsen zu benutzen?<sup>[2]</sup>
>
> (b)   Nur soviel Wasser **zum Kochen bringen**, wie auch wirklich
>   gebraucht wird.<sup>[3]</sup>
>
> (c)   Erklärtes Ziel von Toastmasters ist, dass bei jedem Club-Treffen
>   möglichst alle Anwesenden **zum Sprechen kommen**.<sup>[4]</sup>
>
> (d)   Mögen die Bilder und Texte auf diesen Seiten Sie inspirieren,
>   erfrischen, **zum Weinen bringen**, zum Lachen, Sie ärgern.<sup>[5]</sup>

In examples (a) and (b), there is the sense that after the verb *halten* and *kochen* has acted, the space ship does come to a stop and the water is now boiling, the verb actions are complete.

For (c) and (d), I don’t understand where the meaning of completion is.  If anything, in these examples, the verbs are acting sufficiently enough to indicate that a person is now "talking" or "crying" and leave the next steps open.

Sources:

1. “Hammer’s German Grammar and Usage – 3rd Edition”, Martin Durrell, 1996, Arnold.
2. Linguee search - [zum Halten bringen](https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/zum+Halten+bringen.html)
3. Linguee search - [zum Kochen bringen](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=zum+Kochen+bringen)
4. Linguee search - [zum Sprechen kommen](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=zum+Sprechen+kommen)
5. Linguee search - [zum Weinen bringen](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=zum+Weinen+bringen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bringen zu* plus infinitive can be used to form causatives from intransitive verbs. I see no aspectual component. This is the case for examples a), b), d).

> Sie brachte ihren Bruder zum Weinen.
> *She made her brother cry.*
>
> Sie brachte ihn zum Aufgeben.
> *She made him give up.*
>
> Der Lokomotivführer brachte den Zug zum Stehen.
> "The train driver made the train stand."
> *The train driver brought the train to a halt.*

*Kommen zu* plus infinitive can be used to signify that a state is reached eventually, after a certain amount of time has passed.

> Das Fahrzeug schlitterte an den Straßenrand und kam zum Stehen.
> *The vehicle skidded to the side of the road and came to a halt.*

However, example c) is different. Just as for English *get to*, the meaning seems to have shifted from reaching a certain place to being able to make time for a certain activity.

> Ich komme nie zum Aufräumen.
> *I never have time to clean up.*
>
> Ich hoffe, ich komme heute noch zum Trainieren.
> *I hope I manage to make time for training today*.
>
> Wir kamen nicht dazu, den Louvre zu besuchen.
> *We didn't get to* (or *manage to*) *visit the Louvre*.

These verbs are highly polysemous, so there will be many other uses. For instance, *kommen zu* plus a deverbal noun has a passive meaning.

> Die Polizei setzt Wasserwerfer ein.
> = Die Polizei bringt Wasserwerfer zum Einsatz.
> *The police are using water cannons.*
>
> Wasserwerfer kommen zum Einsatz.
> *Water cannons are being used.*

Also, *zu* itself can be a final preposition, i.e. express a purpose.

> Ich komme zum Trainieren hierher, nicht zum Reden.
> *I go here in order to train, not to talk.*

Comment: Nice analysis. However in "zu itself can be a causal preposition.
Ich komme zum Trainieren hierher, nicht zum Reden.
I go here in order to train, not to talk "zu" is a final and not a causal preposition.